# @media (max-width: 837px) != $(document).width()<837

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, media-queries

Everybody, I try to make a responsive website so I've added media queries
So it's like:

```
@media (min-width: 838px) {
    bigscreen code
}
@media (max-width: 837px) {
    littlescreen code
}
```

But when I do some things with JS like

```
if($(document).width()<837+1){
code
}
```

I've made a console.log($(document).width()). And the css littlescreen code happened when $(document).width() = 820 but I don't know why.
If someone know, thanks you

EDIT:
$(window).width() = $(document).width() = $('body').innerWidth() = $(window).innerWidth() = $(document).innerWidth()

Comment: Well isn't `820` less than `837`??

Comment: @Pointy Yes it is but my media queries act only when js say that width is 820

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding your code inside the event function?

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
               
               console.log($(document).width());
  
               if($(document).width()<837){
                 
                  alert("Less than 837px");
                  
               }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser
 $(document).width(); // returns width of HTML
```

I think, you should try $(window).width()

```
if($(window).width()<837+1){
code
}
```

Comment: I try but same things

Answer (score 0):

According to the @media docs it uses [the `viewport` width, not the `document` width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width).

In the console on this page:

```
window.innerWidth
1936
$(document).width()
1921
```

Perhaps we are talking about the difference being the width of the scrollbar (or something else)?

This site gives you a good guide to different width outputs:
http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

And this one for dealing with browser viewport differences: http://www.matanich.com/2013/01/07/viewport-size/

Comment: There is a scrollbar in my page but all have the same width even with'body' instead of document/window

Comment: interesting..i have different values.  Maybe we are seeing some browser differences [http://www.matanich.com/2013/01/07/viewport-size/](http://www.matanich.com/2013/01/07/viewport-size/)?  Im on Chrome.  What about you?

Comment: I use chrome to. I don't know why